# Using react hooks and functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a conceptual doubt around hooks and functional component in React.

Conceptually you can have 3 types of components:

- class component
- functional component
- pureComponents (using react memo or extending PurComponent)

Now, using hooks on a "functional component" will add state to it, basically we are transforming it to a class component "under the hood" and that broke the concept of purity (now receiving 2 props cannot warranty the output will be the same for different executions, since it can be override by state).

**So the question is:**

If I use a hook on a functional component, it is not anymore a "functional component" per se, but a "functional component with state" ?

Comment: They call it a function component.

Comment: `pureComponents` can still be a `function component`, it's just memoized. Nothing is transforming anything into a class under-the-hood, on the contrary! there are no classes in javascript. only prototypes and functions

Comment: What does it matter how you call it? The concept is that people want to write functions (not classes) and then (or later) add internal state that will cause re-render, in an easy manner. is all.

Comment: Well, having pure componentes is always a great idea (when you can), since that will make a great performance boost. That is why i'm worried about this. Having a "function" and state inside will break purity, hence it will not be performant. Having a class and functional as a separate concept, allows to quickly detect which components are pure or not without hooks. But having hooks inside a function, makes it harder to see that (also adding memo will not work on that case). That's why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish from "stateless functional component" and "function component" that handle state.

We'll probably move away from calling "functional component" non-class component, because it imply the fact that the component is stateless and pure. "Function component" is a better name, because it doesn't have that inherited meaning, since it can hold state and side effects.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use a hook on a functional component, it is not anymore a
>   "functional component" per se, but a "functional component with state"
>   ?

Correct! Stateless (functional) components can now be stateful. Crazy right?

Personally, I think they went a bit too far with the Hooks thing. UseState is fine but shouldn't be used for anything but simple components. Most of the time, I find myself converting back to Stateful Components when things get more complex.

Comment: I don't find myself ever going back to classes. I disliked them the moment it was released into the language and was happy it was gone.

I find hooks great, although it takes quite a while to master them, the benefits are worth it. You have a lot of power in your hands, and if your state is complex, simply use the `useReducer` hook which helps in making order and decoupling. 
I have written many many components with hooks, some are quite complex, spanning hundreds of lines of code, with many hooks, and one things "click" in your mind, it is a delight.